# Pytorch unsqueeze function and concatenating

Tags: concatenation, pytorch, tensor

I have initialized a tensor t2 and applied unsqueeze function

```
t2=torch.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
t2.unsqueeze(dim=0)
tensor([[[1, 2], [3, 4]]])
t2.unsqueeze(dim=1)
tensor([[[1, 2]],[[3, 4]]])
```

Where I have done dim=1, there is a vacant space between the first row and second row, what does it signify?

[[image: enter image description here[1]]